# How to remove quotes from a list to convert it into a tuple

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list which contains:

```
["('apple','banana')","('orange','cherry')"]
```

I want to remove the quotes from the list and convert it into a tuple
I tried to use

```
tuple(list1)
```

But I am getting:

```
 ("('apple','banana')", "('orange','cherry')")
```

OR

I want the output to be:

```
('apple','banana'),('orange','cherry')
```

also this output could help:

```
[('apple','banana'),('orange','cherry')]
```

Comment: How did you get to produce such a list in the first place? `import ast` then `[ast.literal_eval(t) for t in inputlist]` will convert each element to a tuple, but you may want to avoid getting into this pickle in the first place.

Comment: I have a list of cities in the format [a,b,c,d,.......]. I wanted to make a network of those cities which could be visited from any place, like from b to a, c to b, c to a and so on. To make such a network I needed a tuple. So I needed it to convert from list to tuple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `ast.literal_eval` for this purpose, which is safer than `eval`.

```
>>> import ast
>>> x = ["('apple','banana')","('orange','cherry')"]
>>> [ast.literal_eval(i) for i in x]
[('apple', 'banana'), ('orange', 'cherry')]
```

Answer (score -2):

```
In [1]: l = ["('apple','banana')","('orange','cherry')"]
In [2]: map(eval, l)
Out[2]: [('apple', 'banana'), ('orange', 'cherry')]
```

Comment: Slowly back away from using `eval()`. There are very few actual use-cases for the function. This is not one of them.

Comment: ast.literal_eval can be replaced with..

Comment: But not vice versa. That's because `eval()` is a gun aimed at the foot, while `ast.literal_eval()` is a very precise tool that only parses literals.